# How to call http.put() API in flutter using GetX?

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-getx

I have my first screen as a SignUp screen and when I click on signup I save the basic Info like (Name, Ph.No.) and when the user goes to the profile section he can update his profile there.

I want to use HTTP.put() API from NodeJs in my Flutter app using GetX?

Please provide some solution or resources, I didn't get any solution regarding HTTP.put on the internet.

If you need more info, Please comment. Any help is appreciated. thank you.